# Javascript on IE on Windows 7/10 not working properly

Tags: javascript, babeljs, polyfills

So for some reason, the JavaScript that I'm using is not working on IE - There are errors which I will point out below. If someone knows anything else that I can try or knows how I can manipulate the code to make it more IE friendly, I'd really appreciate it.

[image]

[image]

Here are the steps that I've taken:
- Use `https://babeljs.io/` to convert the whole page to ES2015.
- Added a polyfill script tag from `https://polyfill.io/`

**Lots of code below** (Whole general.js file which I've already converted using Babel (**Please let me know if you want me to upload the original general.js file**)):

Everything below `rtd3Confirmation` function is supposed to be:

```
for (var inputElement of rtd3ChangeClass) {
    inputElement.addEventListener('change', rtd3Confirmation);
}
```

but that was before babel converted it.

```js
"use strict";

// Form wrapper variables
var contactFormID = document.getElementById('contactForm');
var formWrapperSpecific = document.getElementById('form-wrapper-specific');
var formWrapperCertainSelection = document.getElementById('form-wrapper-certain-selection');
var formWrapperCertain = document.getElementById('form-wrapper-certain');
var formWrapperConfirm = document.getElementById('rtd3Confirm'); // Alert variables

var stateAlertID = document.getElementById('stateWarning');
var stateQuery = document.querySelector('#stateWarning b#stateName');
var resident = document.getElementById('resident');
var is_submitted = document.getElementsByClassName('is-submitted'); // Right to Know variables

var rtk5_selection = document.getElementById('rtk5');
var rtk5declaration = document.getElementById('rtk5Declaration'); // Right to Delete variables

var rtdChange = document.getElementById('rtd3');
var rtd3ChangeClass = document.querySelectorAll(".rtd3_change"); // Array for states

var states = []; // Once the DOM has loaded, call functions

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    formHandler();
    residentAlert();
    rtdCheckboxSelection();
    rtd3Confirmation();
    rtk5Declaration();
    get_states();
}); // Show/hide form depending if state is included in array on dropdown selection

function formHandler() {
    contactFormID.style.display = 'block';
    if (resident == null) return;
    if (!states.includes(resident.value)) contactFormID.style.display = 'none';
    resident.addEventListener('change', formHandler);
} // Show/hide state alert for non-residents


function residentAlert() {
    if (resident !== null) {
        resident.addEventListener('change', function () {
            // If value in states array is true, show the form
            if (!states.includes(resident.value)) {
                stateAlertID.style.display = 'block';
                stateQuery.textContent = resident.options[resident.selectedIndex].text;
            } else {
                stateAlertID.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    }
} // Show states dropdown depending on PHP variables


function get_states() {
    var data_states = contactFormID.getAttribute('data-states').match(/\w{1,}/g);
    data_states.forEach(function (state, i) {
        return states[i] = state;
    });
} // If RTK5 is selected, show declaration field and set required tag


function rtk5Declaration() {
    if (!rtk5_selection.checked) {
        formWrapperSpecific.style.display = 'none';
        rtk5declaration.removeAttribute('required');
    } else {
        formWrapperSpecific.style.display = '';
        rtk5declaration.setAttribute('required', 'required');
    }
}

rtk5_selection.addEventListener('change', rtk5Declaration); // If RTD3 is selected, show/hide more checkboxes

function rtdCheckboxSelection() {
    formWrapperCertain.style.display = rtdChange.checked ? '' : 'none';
    document.querySelectorAll('[name="rtd[checked]"]').forEach(function (r) {
        return r.addEventListener('change', rtdCheckboxSelection);
    });
} // If at least one checkbox inside rtd3 is checked, show confirmation and make required


function rtd3Confirmation() {
    if (document.querySelectorAll('.rtd3_change:checked').length) {
        formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = '';
        formWrapperConfirm.required = true;
    } else {
        formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = 'none';
        formWrapperConfirm.required = false;
    }
}

var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
var _didIteratorError = false;
var _iteratorError = undefined;

try {
    for (var _iterator = rtd3ChangeClass[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
        var inputElement = _step.value;
        inputElement.addEventListener('change', rtd3Confirmation);
    }
} catch (err) {
    _didIteratorError = true;
    _iteratorError = err;
} finally {
    try {
        if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return != null) {
            _iterator.return();
        }
    } finally {
        if (_didIteratorError) {
            throw _iteratorError;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your polyfill script tag synchronous (not async), and is it loaded before your own script?

Comment: querySelectorAll does not return an array. You should turn it into an array, like `[...document.qsa('selector')].forEach`

Comment: @Frambot, I even popped in a Array.forEach polyfill as shown here `<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2Cdefault%2Ces5%2Ces6%2Ces2016%2CArray.prototype.forEach"></script>` and still no luck. Let me attempt that.

Comment: "[use Babel] _to convert the whole page to ES2015_" . But IE only supports a percent of ES2015. To support IE, you've to configure Babel to convert to ES5.

Comment: @Teemu, I popped in the whole .js file which is what I normally do to adjust to IE and it's worked in the past but I guess with these errors, it's different.

Comment: @SLE What @Frambot is telling you is that since `querySelectorAll` does NOT return an array, the return value (a NodeList) does NOT have `forEach` in its prototype chain, so it really cannot find `forEach`...

Comment: @laruiss Nope, though it really doesn't return an array, the returned NodeList supports `forEach`, please check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Comment: @SLE Which version of IE are you testing?

Comment: > some older browsers have not implemented NodeList.forEach(). @Teemu you should read the big yellow box at the top of the linked doc.

Comment: @Frambot I can't see your point, we're talking about the Babel translated code, it takes care of the DOM/hosted methods too.

Comment: `forEach` is not supported on IE for NodeLists

Comment: @afuggini IE9+ certainly support Array.prototype.forEach

Comment: @Teemu we can see in the code pasted in the original question that Babel is transforming an array forEach, but is leaving the NodeList forEach un-fixed.

Comment: @Frambot Yes! Because SLE said: "_[use Babel] to convert the whole page to __ES2015___", which they should not do, if they wanted to support IE. Instead they should convert to __ES5__. This is what I said in my very first comment on this thread ...

Comment: The comment initially said "[use Babel] to convert the whole page to ES2015" . But IE only supports a percent of ES2015.", did you edit the next sentence? :P

Comment: @Frambot Probably I did edit it, few seconds after posting the comment, it should've been updated along new comments posted ...